# scaling images in iTextSharp

Tags: c#, image, pdf, itext, scaling

I'm having some trouble scaling an image that i am inserting.
I must be doing something wrong, because it does not change at all, no matter what i do.
This is the code i have at the moment, but it does not seem to work.
The image gets inserted fine, it just doesn't scale, no matter what values i try.

Any obvious things i am doing wrong? Any common things that people do wrong?
I am working in C#, but i assume the syntax is the same (more or less) in all languages.

```
    Image imgSpine = Image.GetInstance(strSpine);
    imgSpine.ScaleAbsolute(2, 55);
    SpineCell.Image = imgSpine;

    SpineCell.Image.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
    SpineCell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_TOP;
    SpineCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;

    pTable.AddCell(SpineCell);
```

Comment: What type is `SpineCell`? After you call ScaleAbsolute do `ScaledHeight` and `ScaledWidth` have the values you expcet? Maybe the image is being scaled but its stretching to fit the container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [the source](http://itext.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/itext/trunk/src/core/com/itextpdf/text/), `cell.Image` is always scaled to fit the cell.  You'll want to wrap your image in a `Chunk` or some similar `Element` that'll hold an `Image`.

The `call.Image` property is also always written to a the `PdfPTable.TEXTCANVAS` canvas in the PdfPTable, so you don't have any control over Z order.

Options:

1. Wrap the image in a Chunk instead.
2. Use a Cell Event handler and draw the image yourself.

Number 1 is probably *much* easier.

Comment: You are right. Thanks! I played around abit, and i could use Cell.AddElement() to add the Image directly, without chunk/etc.