# itextsharp and images sizes

Tags: c#, itext

I am creating a single pdf page with 6 images in a table in separate cells, even though I am setting the images height and width on the server side exactly the same with ScaleToFit the images sizes are not the same on the pdf page.

Is there anyway to get all the images the exact same size?

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
table.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
table.WidthPercentage = 100;
table.TotalWidth = 698.5f;
table.LockedWidth = true;
table.SetWidths(new float [] {1,1,1});
iTextSharp.text.Image img1 =    iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance("C:\\Users\\DaNet\\Downloads\\image.jpg");
img1.Alignment = iTextSharp.text.Image.ALIGN_CENTER;
img1.ScaleToFit(120f, 155.25f);

iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell imgCell1 = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell(img1);
imgCell1.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
imgCell1.BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(255, 255, 255);
imgCell1.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
table.AddCell(imgCell1);
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Two things.

First, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990459/scaling-images-in-itextsharp) about wrapping the `Image` in a `Chunk`. Basically:

```
iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell imgCell1 = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell();
imgCell1.AddElement(new Chunk(img1, 0, 0));
```

Second, if you want the ***exact*** same size then you want to use `ScaleAbsolute` instead of `ScaleToFit`. The latter keeps the aspect ratio of the image so a 100x200 image scaled to fit 50x50 would come out as 25x50.

```
img1.ScaleAbsolute(120f, 155.25f);
```

Comment: It look likes the image is the proper size now thanks! Now I have to position it the cell even though it is an element of the cell. In the end I don't think that would be the best alternative for what I am trying to do.

Comment: By just using img1.ScaleAbsolute(120f, 155.25f); the images fit the cell perfectly. Cheers Chris!

Comment: If I want my image 35x35 mm then what should I do? How to calculate it in mm?

Comment: Thankx "ScaleAbsolut" is the solution of my problem.

Comment: Good mention about wrapping in a Chunk. Been wondering why my scaling wasn't working at all!