# Resize image from database with iTextSharp and asp image in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, pdf, itext

On the `public/images` folder in my server I have uploaded the `jpg image` with 2048x1536 pixel and 290 kb.

I have memorized in MySQL table database on the field `Pic` this link : http://mywebserver.xxx/aspx/public/images/IMG0006A.jpg

I need print this image on pdf file using [iTextSharp library](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp) and resized this image because its original file size are off page pdf.

I have find this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234062/itextsharp-and-images-sizes) and I have tried the suggestion without success because in the output the jpg image printed on pdf file is always out page.

How to do resolve this ?

Can you help me?

Thank you in advance, my code below.

**.aspx markup**

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <label for="Pic">
                Pic<br />
            </label>
            <asp:Image ID="Pic" runat="server" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**.cs code-behind**

```
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(reader["Pic"].ToString()))
    {
        lbPic.ImageUrl = reader["Pic"].ToString();
        iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell imgCell1 = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell();
        iTextSharp.text.Image img1 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Server.MapPath("\\public\\images\\IMG0006A.jpg"));
        imgCell1.AddElement(new Chunk(img1, 0, 0));
        img1.ScaleToFit(120f, 155.25f);
        img1.ScaleAbsolute(120f, 155.25f);
    }
```

Comment: I wonder how the image can show at all as both your cell and your image objects are out of range at the end of that snippet without being used otherwise..

Comment: I am not sure you need to use both `ScaleAbsolute` and `ScaleToFit`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use and don't know *iTextSharp library* but I think that you resolve this problem using **resizing image** method in **upload file**.

e.g.

```
private int ResizeMethod(FileUpload upload, int iFileCnt)
{
    Stream strm = upload.PostedFile.InputStream;
    using (var image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(strm))
    {
        int newWidth = 450;
        int newHeight = 350;

        var thumbImg = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
        var thumbGraph = Graphics.FromImage(thumbImg);
        thumbGraph.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        thumbGraph.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        thumbGraph.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        var imgRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
        thumbGraph.DrawImage(image, imgRectangle);

        string extension = Path.GetExtension(upload.PostedFile.FileName);
        string targetPath = Server.MapPath("\\public\\images\\" + upload.FileName.ToString());
        thumbImg.Save(targetPath, image.RawFormat);
        iFileCnt += 1;
    }

    return iFileCnt;
}
```

Hope that this is help for you-