# Image is stretched while Adding into PDF - iText 5 .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext, pdf-generation

I am stamping multiple images in the PDF document being generated from my SharePoint app. The PDF generation & image is stamping is working fine, but the image is changing it's original width & height i.e. the image is getting stretched when added to the PDF.

Here is my code:

```
SPFile PendingimgFile = obj_sign.GetFile("PendingApproval");//Get Image
byte[] imgByte = PendingimgFile.OpenBinary(SPOpenBinaryOptions.None);
MemoryStream ms_img = new MemoryStream(imgByte);

iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(ms_img);
image.SetAbsolutePosition(HorizontalValue, verticalValue);

image.ScaleAbsolute(80f, 60f);

cb.AddImage(image);//PDF Content byte
```

I've gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234062/itextsharp-and-images-sizes)

The image quality is becoming very poor due to stretching, following is the screenshot from the PDF File:

[image]

Comment: You call `image.ScaleAbsolute(80f, 60f)`, so you explicitly set the resulting image size to 80×60 user space units. If you don't want these dimensions, don't set them.

Comment: @mkl I have already tried the same,it didn't work

Comment: *"I have already tried the same,it didn't work"* - Probably you did something wrong. You have not mentioned yet the actual size of the bitmap (probably you should share it). You don't show what content byte the `cb` is. (Direct or under content of a page? Some arbitrary template? Some annotation appearance?) In particular you don't show whether it is subject to any transformations.